# Integrating Restful web service API into my woo commerce website

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a **wordpress** ***woo commerce*** website.

I have made a contract with a ***delivery company*** which has its own `API`,

so in order to **track my orders** and to **generate bar codes**, i have to integrate a `RESTful web service` that accepts `POST` requests and returns `JSON` responses, as described by the company.

They sent an **`API key`** and a **`link to offline server`** in order to make a test

I have read the woo commerce official documentations:

- [Woo Commerce Rest API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)
- [Getting started with the REST API](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API)
- [woocommerce rest api docs](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

but they all say to generate API key and not to integrate external API key into the website, i don't need to understand how to code, i want to understand the process in general.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the carrier in question.  There are a number of carrier plugins already available for WooCommerce that you can choose from that integrate with mainstream carriers.

If it is not a mainstream carrier, then you will need to create a custom plugin to use their API (that is beyond the scope of answering here, see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/).  You could also potentially market this back to the carrier.

Alternatively, you could write a separate process that polls the WooCommerce API for orders, and then connects with the carrier API to create consignments.  I've not written plugins for WooCommerce, but have experience with APIs in general, so if it was me, personally, I'd go this way.